# Toast в Android 4+

Tags: android

Обнаружил, что в четвертом андроиде не всплывают тосты, как можно их реализовать?

upd: я в `OnCreate` писал:

```
mToast = Toast.makeText( this  , "" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
```

потом где мне надо делал

```
mToast.cancel();
mToast.setText("Текст");
mToast.show();
```

(Все это для того что бы больше одного тоста не показывалось! )
в 2.3 это работает в 4 - нет!

Может подскажет кто, как правильно сделать, что бы тосты не накапливались, а при вызове предыдущий отменялся?

Comment: Ты уверен, что в ICS нет тостов?! Этого не может быть! Они там точно есть - проверь, а потом пиши!

Comment: У меня приложение всё в тостах, пользователь пишет что в 4.0.3 тосты не всплывают, подрубаю эмулятор и правда!

Comment: Сегодня вечером проверю на эмуляторе... Вообще странно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил на эмуляторе ICS - тосты есть. Доступа к девайсу нет так, что ничего сказать не могу, но нет оснований не доверять миллионам пользователей.

Есть небольшая проблемка с тостами в ICS - они очень маленькие - возможно ваш юзер их просто не видит. Как [пишет народ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658059/android-toast-notification-is-too-small-in-ice-cream-sandwich), проблема решается вставкой в манифест декларации поддержки больших разрешений:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Неправда ваша, есть они там и никуда не девались.

Comment: Факт остается фактом! может я по-кривому их вызываю просто, что в четверке тупо не всплывают

Comment: Ну дык. Документацию читать не пробовали? Иногда бывает полезно.

public void cancel ()

Since: API Level 1
Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet. You do not normally have to call this. Normally view will disappear on its own after the appropriate duration.

Answer (score 3):

Toast-ы прекрасно работают как на эмуляторе так и на реальном девайсе, проверено.
В ICS не настолько кардинально все поменяли, чтобы убрать тоасты. Вообще в системе, UI которой идеологически построен на диалогах, всплывающих окнах и прочей popup-фигни вот так резко взяли и убрали всплывающие подсказки.
У меня есть единственное подозрение в том, что у вашего "пользователя, который отрапортовал отсутствие тостов" может стоять какая-то очень кастрированная фирмварь. На моей практике были жалобы от одного юзера о вылете приложения, как потом выяснилось у него стоит MUIU. И красавцы-разрабы этой фирмвари как-то по своему переопределили стандартные табы, толи индексацию нарушили то ли еще что-то (не помню уже точно)